# magento attributes filter only in last (level 3) category

Tags: magento, attributes, e-commerce, layered-navigation

I have category hierarchy up to level 3. ex,

```
Root Category 
Category 1
    Category 1.1
        Category 1.1.1
        Category 1.1.2
        Category 1.1.3
    Category 1.2
        Category 1.2.1
        Category 1.2.2
        Category 1.2.3
    Category 1.3
Category 2
.       .       .
.       .       .
.       .       .
```

**Question**
While browsing categories in layered navigation, the product's attribute's filters are displaying in all layers but i want to attribute filter in only last category (eg. 3rd level category). How to do that

Note: I have searched it a lot but on one question of magento meta, one answer was altering css to hide filters in particular page. but i want to do it on higher level ( without css and if possible then php hacks).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display `layered navigation` in level-3 only, you need to set a condition inside the template that render layered navigation block.

Layered navigation block is rendering by the template `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml`. You have to modify  the content as shown below

```
<?php
if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getData('level')== 4):
?>
      <?php 
         /**
           * Content in the template comes here :)
           *
           * Add content in this file, inside this condition
           */
      ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What we are done here is, we get the current category level using the method `Mage::registry('current_category')` and check whether it is `level-4`. If yes renders the content. else it will not.

Note : What you have described as level-3 in your context is actually `level-4`. That is because, magento counts `root-category` as `level-1`

Thats it. That will do the trick. Enjoy coding. Let me know if you  have any doubts.

### **EDIT**

So you need to display category navigation in all category levels, but need to show other filter attributes in level-4 only. If that is the case, let us implement it.

As I already stated, `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` is the starting point of layered navigation blocks. In that file you can see that, it invokes below method

```
 <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
```

to show the layered navigation content. This method is defined in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View` class and the file is in the location `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php`. Let us analyze this method.

```
public function getFilters()
{
    $filters = array();
    if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
        $filters[] = $categoryFilter;
    }

    $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
    foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
        $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
    }


    return $filters;
}
```

Here you can see that, when we call this method, it returns an array, i e `$filters`. Again you can see that, `category-filter` and `attributes-filter` are storing in `$filters` separately. So we are lucky. What we need to do is, include the `attribute-filters` to `$filters` array only when we are standing in level-4. You can easily achieve this by changing code in this format.

```
 public function getFilters()
{
    $filters = array();
    if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
        $filters[] = $categoryFilter;
    }

    $current_layer = Mage::registry('current_category')->getData('level');

    if($current_layer == 4) {
        $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
        foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
            $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
        }
    }


    return $filters;
}
```

Thats it. you are done. But its not a good practice to change a core files. So in order to keep core files untouched, let us create a tiny `module` that overwrites this class. You just need only 3 files in your module.

1. **config.xml**

**Location :`app/code/local/Programmerrkt/Layerednav/etc/config.xml`**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Programmerrkt_Layerednav>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Programmerrkt_Layerednav>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks> 
            <!-- rewrites Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View -->
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <layer_view>Programmerrkt_Layerednav_Block_Layer_View</layer_view>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

`config.xml` tells to magento that I am going to overwrite the core block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View`.

2. **Programmerrkt_Layerednav.xml**

**Location :`app/etc/modules/Programmerrkt_Layerednav.xml`**

```
 <config>
    <modules>
        <Programmerrkt_Layerednav>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Programmerrkt_Layerednav>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This file activates our module.

3. **View.php**

**Location : `app/code/local/Programmerrkt/Layerednav/Block/Layer/View.php`**

```
<?php

class Programmerrkt_Layerednav_Block_Layer_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View {

     /**
     * Get all layer filters
     *
     * This method Overwrites getFilter() method of class Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View
     *
     * Adds attribute filter only when category leve is 4
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        $filters = array();
        if ($categoryFilter = $this->_getCategoryFilter()) {
            $filters[] = $categoryFilter;
        }

        $current_layer = Mage::registry('current_category')->getData('level');

        if($current_layer == 4) {
            $filterableAttributes = $this->_getFilterableAttributes();
            foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
                $filters[] = $this->getChild($attribute->getAttributeCode() . '_filter');
            }
        }


        return $filters;
    }
}
```

This will overwrite the core class.

Now clear the cache and reload the pages. Check whether it worked or not. Remember that you need to remove all changes that you made to the file `view.phtml`

Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot. in this way the whole left layered navigation gets disapper, including attribute filters and category also. But what i want to do is, i want to display only categories in layered navigation .. please help ..

Comment: I have edited my answer. please go through it and let me know whether it worked